# how does one create a trailing path in cesium?

Tags: cesiumjs

I would like to have a trailing orange path behind movement of my billboard entity. I am pro grammatically controlling its movement (it is coming from a live remote sensor). The the actual SVG/Canvas for the symbol comes from: https://github.com/spatialillusions/milsymbol

But the point is that I am clearly making an error in how to setup the PATH attribute of the entity. I don't see a trailing or leading path. What am I doing wrong?

```
    makeGlyph(sprite) {
    let milSym = milSymbols[sprite.type]
    if (milSym === undefined) milSym = milSymbols["UFO"]
    sprite.mps = 0
    sprite.symbol = milSym
    let sym2 = new ms.Symbol(milSym, { size: 26, type: sprite.marking, speed: sprite.mps + ' mps', direction: sprite.heading, infoColor: "red" })
    let glyph = new Cesium.Entity({
        name: sprite.marking,
        id: sprite.id,
        position: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(sprite.lon, sprite.lat, sprite.altitude),
        billboard: {
            image: sym2.asCanvas(), //Get the canvas for the billboard
            // heightReference : Cesium.HeightReference.CLAMP_TO_GROUND,
            pixelOffset: new Cesium.Cartesian2(-sym2.markerAnchor.x, -sym2.markerAnchor.y), // Symbol offset
            eyeOffset: new Cesium.Cartesian3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), // default
            horizontalOrigin: Cesium.HorizontalOrigin.LEFT, // default
            verticalOrigin: Cesium.VerticalOrigin.TOP
        },
        path: {
            leadTime: 100,
            trailTime: 100,
            width: 1,
            material: new Cesium.ColorMaterialProperty({
                color : Cesium.Color.ORANGE,
            })
        },
        label: {
            text: sprite.marking,
            font: '14pt monospace',
            style: Cesium.LabelStyle.FILL_AND_OUTLINE,
            outlineWidth: 1,
            verticalOrigin: Cesium.VerticalOrigin.BOTTOM,
            pixelOffset: new Cesium.Cartesian2(0, -20)
        }
    })
    sprite.glyph = glyph
    this.infoBox(sprite)
    this.viewer.entities.add(glyph)
}
updateGlyph(sprite) {
    this.viewer.entities.suspendEvents()
    let loc = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(sprite.lon, sprite.lat, sprite.altitude)
    sprite.mps = sprite.speed[0] + sprite.speed[1] + sprite.speed[2]
    sprite.glyph.position = loc;
    this.infoBox(sprite)
    this.viewer.entities.resumeEvents()
}
```

Comment: The problem isn't `path`, it's `position`.  If you want to show the trail, you need a `SampledPositionProperty`.  You can add positions to the property over time, but you need to hold onto the old positions and not just overwrite them.

Comment: Do you know of an example using the api (I.e. not czml like: https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/czml-writer/wiki/CZML-Structure ) to programmatically add an epoch and append on time samples, or even something that partially does something like that.